# What is the definition of "reactionary chic"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the headline ["The awful advent of reactionary chic"](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/25/opinion/reactionary-new-right.html) from the NY Times, is "reactionary chic" a known expression? I didn't find it on google. Also I read all the article repeatadly and did not get what is a reactionary chic. Is that a neologism?

Comment: May I suggest editing your question to add a link to the original Opinion column on the New York Times website? It is here: <https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/25/opinion/reactionary-new-right.html> (Michelle Goldberg, "The Awful Advent of Reactionary Chic," New York Times, 25 April 2022).

Comment: From [*Harpers*](https://harpers.org/archive/1995/03/reactionary-chic/) magazine (1995?) "**Reactionary chic** How the nineties right recycles the bombast of the sixties left". [More here](https://www.gornahoor.net/?p=9149) on **Reactionary chic**.

Comment: As with 'shabby chic', it is a **compound adjective**.

Comment: @WeatherVane - not a noun in this case?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I guess so, as the name of a style.

Comment: reactionry chic like the horrible offspring of the Orange Man.

Comment: @Lambie - your man from the Six Counties?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, the former US president and his execrable progeny.

Answer (score 2):

Phrases such as *something* chic are an often sarcastic way of suggesting that something is a fad or fashion. For example 'Nazi chic' is the use of style, imagery, and paraphernalia in clothing and popular culture related to Nazi-era Germany, especially when used for taboo-breaking or shock value rather than out of genuine sympathies with Nazism or Nazi ideology. Other examples include 'vampire chic' where people wear costumes and makeup inspired by vampires portrayed in horror films, 'retro chic' when people decorate their houses in styles from, and buy furniture from, previous decades, and 'military chic' when people wear clothes whose design is inspired by, or mimics, military uniforms in some way.

The somewhat sarcastic New York Times opinion article from which the quote comes reports someone writing that the US far-right (political) movement has become fashionable ('chic') among (for example) people in 'new tech outposts like Miami and Austin, and in downtown Manhattan'.

> chic ​NOUN UNCOUNTABLE
>
> an attractive fashionable style that people admire

[Chic (noun) (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chic_2)

Comment: 'new tech outposts like Miami and Austin, and in downtown Manhattan' - whether this means American democracy is doomed, or not, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, to the best of my knowledge, the phrase "Reactionary Chic" is a neologism.** More specifically, it is **a neologism that was coined to allude to the phrase ["Radical Chic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_chic),** which *is* a well-known, common expression in literary and journalistic English.

In context, the author — Michelle Goldberg, a regularly contributing Left-wing columnist for the *New York Times* — is using the phrase **"Reactionary Chic"** to refer to (what she perceives to be) efforts by political or cultural conservatives to adopt a *fashionably* ("chic") shocking or outrageous stance towards the mainstream or Establishment cultural institutions by means of extremist Right-wing, anti-Leftist, anti-Progressive or anti-liberal positions or rhetoric.

#### The specific phrase "Reactionary Chic" is not widely used in English, and appears to be a new coinage.

The author of the Opinion column that you read ([Michelle Goldberg, "The Awful Advent of Reactionary Chic," *New York Times* 25 April 2022](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/25/opinion/reactionary-new-right.html)) is not the only person ever to use the phrase. For example, another journalist, Steve Erickson, used the same phrase in 2019 in ["Reactionary Chic," his book review of a recent essay collection by the American author Bret Easton Ellis](https://gaycitynews.com/reactionary-chic/). But it is not a common phrase in widespread usage in English, at least not to the best of my knowledge.

Almost all the examples of the phrase that I could find on the World Wide Web were references to Michelle Goldberg's Opinion column; even where they were not, it was overwhelmingly used in articles that actually introduce the phrase in the title of the article. This suggests that it is generally a term that is being coined (and has been independently re-invented a few different times) in order to explain a point, rather than being put into widespread use.

#### "___ Chic" is a common pattern for English phrases about fashion or trends.

There are many pre-existing phrases in English that make use of word ["Chic"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chic#English) in order to describe a phenomenon as part of a *fashionable* look or trend. "Chic" is a loan-word borrowed from French, for "elegant; stylish"; it was borrowed into English because it was widely used in the language of international fashions in clothing, cosmetics and design.

In these phrases the noun or adjective put in front of "chic" is typically used as a [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) to refer to a group of people, sub-culture, movement or social practice who the style is supposed to evoke or refer to. For example: ["heroin chic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin_chic) (describes a style in 1990s fashion that was associated with references to drug sub-culture), ["geek chic"](https://www.infobloom.com/what-is-geek-chic.htm) (referring to the employment or fashionable appropriation of styles and lifestyles associated with "geeky" subcultures like hacking and computer programming, video gaming, comics fandom, etc.), ["retro chic"](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=retro+chic&ia=web) (describing styles that draw on self-conscious appeals to  dated fashions, often mid-20th, early 20th or late 19th century, in dress, interior design or material culture), etc. etc. etc.

#### In particular, Michelle Goldberg seems pretty clearly to be coining her phrase as an allusion to a better-known, pre-existing phrase, "Radical Chic."

In ***["Radical Chic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_chic)***,  the word "radical" here refers to *political radicalism,* in particular *radically Left-wing politics*. The word "reactionary" in Goldberg's "Reactionary Chic" refers to its opposite, i.e., *reactionary*, *counter-revolutionary*, or *far Right* politics.

"Radical chic" was a term used very widely in American English in the late 1960s and the 1970s, especially in journalism and literature. It continues to be used as a common phrase today. ["Radical Chic" was the title of a much-discussed essay in 1970 by the essayist Tom Wolfe](https://nymag.com/docs/07/05/070529radical_chic.pdf) published in *New York* Magazine, and later became one of the title essays in his collection *[Radical Chic & Mau-Mauing the Flak Catchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_Chic_%26_Mau-Mauing_the_Flak_Catchers)*, which includes several essays about American culture, the counter-culture, liberals and the far Left in the late 1960s.

Here is how Wikipedia explains the concept of "radical chic" as discussed by Wolfe and others who used the same phrase. (These are claims that Wolfe and others make about the people or events they describe as practicing "radical chic"; of course, it's a separate question whether that's the *correct* way to understand the folks described that way.)

> Radical chic is the fashionable practice of [upper-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper-class) people associating with [politically radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_radicalism) people and causes. Coined in a 1970 essay by journalist [Tom Wolfe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Wolfe), the term has become widely used in languages such as American English, French and Italian.
>
> Unlike dedicated activists, revolutionaries, or dissenters, those who engage in "radical chic" remain frivolous political agitators—ideologically invested in their cause of choice only so far as it advances their social standing.
>
> The concept has been described as "an exercise in double-tracking one's public image: on the one hand, defining oneself through committed allegiance to a radical cause, but on the other, vitally, demonstrating this allegiance because it is the fashionable, [*au courant*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_courant) way to be seen in moneyed, name-conscious Society."[1] [Bracewell, Michael (November-December 2004). "Molotov Cocktails". ''Frieze Magazine'').]
>
> —[Wikipedia: Radical chic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_chic)

**Since "Reactionary" is a common opposite for "Radical," it seems that Goldberg intends to coin a phrase that refers to a similar practice of taking a fashionable anti-Establishment stance, not by means of associating with people from the radical Left, but by taking stances or associating with political causes of reactionary politics,** of the far Right, or of opposition to common liberal and progressive nostrums, in ways which the "Reactionary Chic" practitioner expects to be "edgy," shocking or outrageous.

#### Caveats

Of course, it is perhaps needless to say that all of these terms are terms which are usually used ironically, critically or sarcastically, and which are used in very polemical political and cultural controversies, usually to describe practices, styles, political stances, etc. which the user of the phrase does not identify with, does not consider themselves a part of, and which they may often find wrong-headed, silly, or sometimes ridiculous, contemptible or deeply objectionable. It is relatively straightforward to describe *what real people or events they have been used to describe*, and also *what they are meant to convey about those people or events*, but it is quite another question about whether the people using the terms are consistently, accurately or fairly describing the people or events they use them for, whether what they mean to convey about folks using these terms is true or false, whether they are right or wrong about them, etc. etc. I don't know whether Tom Wolfe was right about that party in New York City in support of the Black Panthers, or whether Goldberg is right about "edgy" Internet Right-wingers, etc. etc.; I'm just trying to explain here some of what they mean by what they are saying, whether they are right or wrong to say it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135880/discussion-on-answer-by-alabamascholiast-what-is-the-definition-of-reactionary).